# Is there any difference between Bokeh server and Bokeh JS in terms of speed?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm working on an application with Bokeh server, which will be embedded into a Django app. The dataframe is quite large, and the application runs slow, especially when using the Select and Slider widgets and Bokeh tools. At the moment I can't understand the difference between Bokeh server (Python Callbacks) and Bokeh JS (CustomJS Callbacks). From your experience, is it possible for Bokeh JS to run faster? Thank you!

Comment: Just noting that this question as stated is not really answerable in general. For one, BokehJS is *always* used, even by Bokeh server apps. So I *think* you are asking "server vs not-server."  But mostly, performance of a Bokeh server app depends heavily on lots of factors (amount of data xferred, local network vs remote usage, how much compute you do...) Any answer depends on the specifics of what your situation. A better question, especially for SO, would be to describe exactly what you are doing (and how) with sufficient code and detail to ask "What ways can this be improved?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make it run faster *once the page and all the plots are loaded*. The initial loading may as well be slower simply because you will have to load *all* the data so it could be used in JS without having to communicate with the server.

With that being said, it's absolutely possible to just combine two approaches. But it requires a deeper understanding of Bokeh's architecture and models.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Is there any link where I can find an example in which the two approaches are combined?

Comment: Not that I know of, no. But it's not conceptually complicated - you just use `CustomJS` in a `bokeh serve` app.